# Aggregate function within inner select in Pivot query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have the following table:

```
select * from product;

slno  item
---------------
1     HDD
2     PenDrive
3     RAM
4     DVD
5     RAM
6     HDD
7     RAM
7     RAM
7     RAM
```

Now I need to do pivoting for this table for which i am using following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(item) 
                from product
                group by item
                  order by item
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT slno,TotalProduct ,' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
            select slno,Count(*) as TotalProduct,item
            from product
            group by slno,item
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            count(item)
            for item in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

exec(@query)
```

Result:

```
 slno  TotalProducts  DVD  HDD  PenDrive  RAM
 ---------------------------------------------
 1         1           0    1      0       0
 2         1           0    0      1       0
 3         1           0    0      0       1
 4         1           1    0      0       0
 5         1           0    0      0       1
 6         1           0    1      0       0
 7         3           0    0      0       1
```

**Note** The total of product RAM is 3 but in Column RAM showing only 1. I have used `COUNT(*)` aggregate function within the inner select statement in `@query`. How can i show actual count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to group by `slno`, not by the combination of `slno` and `item`. Therefore, you need to change the query which provides a source for your pivot as follows:

```
set @query = 'SELECT slno,totalproduct,' + @cols + ' 
    from 
    (
        select p.slno slno, c.count as totalproduct, p.item
        from product p
        inner join 
        (select slno, count(item) count
         from product 
         group by slno) c on p.slno = c.slno
    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        count(item)
        for item in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BCIY12966)

Answer (score 1):

Use following sub query instead of your sub query:

```
select slno,Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY slno) as TotalProduct,item
from product
```

**Edit:** `Count(*) Over(Partition by ...)` supported in SQL Server 2012 and above versions.

Comment: Have you checked your script before posting?

Comment: `Count(*) Over (Partition by)` supported in SQL Server 2012 and above version.

Comment: the result of my query completely like result of shree.pat sub query.

Comment: Oh! "Apologize" I am using 2008. Plz edit your answer so that I can up vote it.